# Cannot connect Spring App docker container to MySQL DB docker container

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, docker

I am having difficulty setting up two containers. One MySQL instance, and another a Spring Application (built with Maven) which wants to talk to the MySQL instance.

I am not sure if there is something wrong with how the ports are matching up, but I have created a network "shape-shop-network", on which both the application "shapeshop" and the database "shape-shop-db-container" should talk to each other through.

Both my "docker run" specify the correct network.

These are the steps I have taken :

1. create a network "shape-shop-network" for both containers.

> ```
> docker network create shape-shop-network
> ```

2. Run MySQL container setting port to **3306**, making sure to specify the "shape-shop-network"

> ```
> docker run -d -p 3306:3306 --name=shape-shop-db-container --network shape-shop-network --env="MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root" --env="MYSQL_PASSWORD=root" --env="MYSQL_DATABASE=shapeshop" mysql
> ```

...followed by adding some schema and initial data :

> ```
> docker exec -i shape-shop-db-container mysql -uroot -proot shapeshop < SCHEMA_AND_INIT_DATA.sql
> ```

3. Specify my application properties in my Spring application

> ```
> spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
> spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/shapeshop?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false
> spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
>         
> spring.datasource.username=root
> spring.datasource.password=root
> spring.datasource.platform=mysql
> spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
> ```

4. Do a Maven Package (to create new jar files which are put in target)
5. Do a Docker Build. My Docker file looks like this :

> ```
> FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
> RUN addgroup -S spring && adduser -S spring -G spring
> USER spring:spring
> ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
> COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
> ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
> EXPOSE 8080
> ```

The command I run is

```
docker build -t shapeshop:1.0 .
```

Then I run my image like so (on port **8080**):

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 shapeshop:1.0 --network shape-shop-network
```

The exception i get is :

```
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar!/:8.0.16]
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar!/:8.0.16]
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar!/:8.0.16]
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar!/:8.0.16]
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:91) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar!/:8.0.16]
        at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:152) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar!/:8.0.16]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:955) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar!/:8.0.16]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:825) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar!/:8.0.16]
        ... 103 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:155) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar!/:8.0.16]
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:65) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar!/:8.0.16]
```

Strangely I can run my application through my IDE (IntelliJ) where it connects correctly to the container.

My IDE settings look like this :

[image]

Comment: In the spring-boot app, what is the database host you are using, i.e. what database-host is configured in the jdbc url?

Comment: You need to use the other container's name `shape-shop-db-container` as the database hostname; `localhost` generally means "this container" in Docker.  I'd suggest injecting it via an environment variable `-e SPRING_DATA_SOURCE_URL=...`.

Comment: thanks !... I tried spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://shape-shop-db-container:3306/shapeshop?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false
   .... but I get an "unkown host exception" Is my string correct?